# 120v AC to 220v AC converter, most cost effective way

Tags: ac, converter

I bought a vintage russian tube clock on ebay, it expects 220v AC.

What is the best solution I can build myself? With the intention of installing in the case and soldering connections to.

I am also open to small existing products that can be modified.

The clock : https://www.glaver.org/blog/?p=419

The page linked above mentions modifying the internal transformer to take 120V, however it does not go into detail about which jumper to remove to achieve this. How would I determine which jumper to remove on my own?

Comment: It would help to know the input current or power. I suspect that purchasing a small step-up transformer will be the best option. The clock probably has a transformer. You might want to measure its core. That will give you a good idea what is required if the input current or power is not marked on the clock.

Comment: You should check what the clock uses as a time base - if it uses the AC power line, I'd expect it to be designed for 50 Hz power - it would run 20% fast on 60 Hz.

Comment: Autotransformer.

Comment: Agree with Peter Bennett, unless you're on 120V 50Hz, the frequency will be your real problem. The voltage difference can be simply handled by a transformer.

Comment: @PeterBennett the clock does not use the power line frequency for timing.

Comment: I have edited the original post to include a link to the clock in question.

Comment: Have you tried to contact the author of the linked post? To get help here to determine how the transformer is wired, it would help to have good pictures of the transformer from better angles. I would use an external transformer at least temporarily. An external transformer would allow voltage measurements that might help.

Comment: What is shown of the transformer in the linked material does not appear to be consistent with dual-voltage primary wiring that is familiar to me.

Comment: @CharlesCowie I have reached out to the author and am waiting for a reply. I can take photos of the transformer in the clock that I have and create another question here, I will include your username to get your contributions. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

To answer your actual question "How would I determine which jumper to remove on my own?", simply measure resistance starting from any pin on the power plug and working your way to the other. If you see definite midpoint then that would be the one to move one power wire to.

Note, that the disconnected winding will now act as secondary and have full 120V on its terminals so, be careful with that.

Another thing to consider is heating of the transformer - with this change the primary winding will carry twice as much current as before. Maybe small step-up transformer would be a better option after all.

Answer (score 0):

The clock is probably low power (maybe 10W), so a modest step-up transformer could work. Something like this: https://voltage-converter-transformers.com/collections/light-duty-travel-110-220v-converter/products/vm-250-f-light-duty-step-up-converter-w-fuse-50w

If you could figure out the clock’s primary winding connection it may be possible to reconfigure it for 120V. Hard to tell with the info given.

Answer (score 0):

If the transformer was designed for both 220V & 110V use, it will likely have two primary windings.

In the 220V case, the "bottom" of one winding will be linked to the "top" of the other, whilst the outer legs will go to the mains supply.

To convert to 110V use, you remove the link, and connect the freed terminal on each winding to the mains feed pin on the other winding.  This parallels  the two windings to allow 110V operation at double the current.